# Replacing a specific character in php

Tags: php, separator

I have a variable having a path to a file which is like the following:

```
$path = "\home\ashutosh\Desktop\imgdone\0001.jpeg"
```

I want that `\` be replaced by this `/` in order for me to read that path. I have used `str_replace()` function to replace but the PHP code is not able to recognize that.

```
str_replace( "\", "/", $path );
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to escape the `\` like that : `str_replace('\\', '/', $path);`

I explain a bit : `"\"` tell php to not end at the quote that follow `\`.

you use it in this case : `"hello I'm \"The Cat\", the super hero"`. so the `\` is a special char, used to escape the one that follow. if you want to use it, you need to escape it with himself : `\\`